# Mysqli: Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

I'm trying to convert a login function into class with some functions, it was working until I converted it into class, this is my code:

```
class merwaa_login {
public $conn;
public function __construct($conn) {
    $this->conn = $conn;
    if(isset($_POST['login-submit'])) {
    $username = merwaa_clean($_POST['username']);
    $password = merwaa_clean($_POST['password']);
    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?;");
    $sql->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
    $sql->execute();
    $all = $sql->get_result();
    $all = $all->fetch_assoc();
    if (count($all) === 0){
        echo 'البيانات المدخلة خاطئة!';
    }
    else{
        $hashed_pwd = $all['password'];
        if (password_verify($password,$hashed_pwd)) {
            echo 'كفو';
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username = $all['username'];
            if(isset($POST['rememberme'])) {
                $uid = $all['ID'];
                merwaa_set_jwt($username,$uid);
            }

        } else{
            echo 'خطأ';
        }
    }
}
}
}
```

May I've some grammar mistakes, please notice me about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this :-

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?;");
```

To this :-

```
$sql = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR email = ?;");
```

Or, you could change `public $conn` to `global $conn`. Then you won't need to make the above change.

Comment: I tried to change `public` to `global`, it says `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in`, what the difference?

Comment: when I use the first solution I got the sme `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null `

Comment: Are you even including the db connection file in your class file?

Comment: Wow! I include it now, you slove it! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$this->conn->prepare` instead of $conn->prepare
and a proper connection object should be passed to the constructor

Comment: the same `Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null `

Comment: you need to pass a proper connection object $conn. like $marwa = new merwaa_login($conn) where $conn is a previously set connection object

Comment: I did `$login = new merwaa_login($conn);`

Comment: but now it's sloved! thanks!